# Prevent CORS - Ajax GET to Nginx Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nginx, cors

I am using Nginx for web server, I did this

```
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  .*;


    #
    # Wide-open CORS config for nginx
    #
    location / {


        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;


        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make an Ajax GET to that VM IP

```
@extends('layouts.admin.master')
@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <iframe id="test" src="" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
@stop

@section('custom-scripts')

<script type="text/javascript">

    var url = "http://172.18.57.62:3000/d-solo/tEnKhjQmk/boss-mbn-clients-detailed-info?orgId=1&var-VM_NAME=87d8f990-b538-11e9-a5d9-0050568d9fc1&var-SESSION_NAME=MBN_UE&panelId=2" ;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true,
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer eyJrIjoidlRmTlg4VnNUdXZ0RktGU2p5UGhwTmtieFN1R1ZyTkoiLCJuIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpZCI6MX0=");
        },
        success: function(data){

            console.log('%c SUCCESS --', "color: green;");

            $("#test").attr('src',url)
            $("#test").contents().find('html').html(data);
        }, error: function (error) {

            console.log('%c ERROR --', "color: red;");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

</script>

@stop
```

I kept getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://172.18.57.62:3000/d-solo/tEnKhjQmk/boss-mbn-clients-detailed-info?orgId=1&var-VM_NAME=87d8f990-b538-11e9-a5d9-0050568d9fc1&var-SESSION_NAME=MBN_UE&panelId=2' from origin 'http://boss.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

[image]

Comment: See here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and look for "cross-domain" (sorry, no time for a more elaborate answer)

Comment: @PeterB I added `xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true,
  },` -- yield same result.

Answer (score 1):

The message is trying to tell you what is wrong:

```
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be
the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

This means that the browser is not satisfied with seeing **`*`** in the response.

To fix this, you need to change what the server returns.

To start, you can change the server script to return **`boss.test`** because we know that the XHttpRequest will be happening from a page hosted on that domain name, and the browser needs to see that domain name echoed back to it.

Example:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'boss.test';
```

If that works, you can make it more versatile (and more secure): change the script to retrieve the `Origin` value that is contained in the request, compare it to a list of valid domain names (that you determine), and if found, reply with the same Origin value that you received, else use an empty string.

Comment: Adding this `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'boss.test';` on the Ajax side or server side ?

Comment: Server side (replace/edit all the existing lines that set it to `'*'`)